# How to use Boost C++ library with Omnet++

Tags: c++, boost, omnet++

I am trying to use boost c++ library with my omnet++ project. I installed boost library version 1_58_0 in windows. But whenever I try to build my omnet++ project it shows an error -

```
cannot find -lboost_filesystem_mt
cannot find -lboost_system_mt
```

Please let me know how to resolve this. Or perhaps I may be wrong in installing and linking boost with omnet++. Let me know the correct way to do so in windows.

Comment: where did you install boost? Have you told the linker where to find it? (hint: library paths)

Comment: I installed in C:/boost_1_58_0 and mentioned library path as C:/boost_1_58_0/stage/lib

Comment: you built it from scratch or installed binaries? stage is where libraries are built to prior to installation.

Comment: wait, -lboost_filesystem etc is the unix command line way of specifying a library. Doesn't the microsoft linker use a response file instead? Suggest using your IDE to include libraries rather than adding command line options.

Comment: I downloaded the boost_1_58_0 zip file and used     bootstrap.bat mingw and then     b2 toolset=gcc

Comment: ok probably best if you post a script that exactly replicates the problem in the smallest number of steps, starting from scratch (probably one source file of  3 lines is enough for your main.cpp) then we can replicate and help you.

Comment: Can you tell me the steps for installing and linking boost library with omnet++ from scratch in windows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84382/discussion-between-richard-hodges-and-sampi).

Comment: it would be helpful to see what flags you passed to the OMNeT++ Makefile creator `opp_makemake` and to see what commands the Makefile is currently executing to build your simulation (that is, the output of `make V=1`.

Answer (score 1):

You should look for files `libboost_system_mt.a` and `libboost_filesystem_mt.a` on your drive. If these files **exist** (for example in `c:\boost_1_58_0\lib`), in OMNeT++ go to your project properties, then `OMNeT++` | `Makemeke` | check the directory with your sources | `Options` | `Custom` | `Makefrag`, and add the path to the *.a libraries, for example: 
`LIBS += -Lc:/boost_1_58_0/lib`
Note that here you should use `/` symbol in path.

Answer (score -1):

make sure your boost install /usr/lib or /usr/lib64 or /usr/local/lib

as I know no boost lib name boost_filesystem_mt  it name's boost_filesystem

Comment: There is a `/usr/lib` on Windows?